# Doesn't JavaFX (or Java) need additional support for Java 8 Lambdas?

Tags: java, javafx, lambda, javafx-8

When using a lambda expression to add a listener to some JavaFX property, we might fall into a classic trap where we will be facing memory leaks or where the listener we set won't be invoked:

```
void init() {
    someProperty.addListener(this::onChanged); // might create a memory leak
    someProperty.addListener(new WeakChangeListener<String>(this::onChanged)); // no memory leak, but the listener won't be called
}
```

The following solution works:

```
private final ChangeListener<String> changeListener = this::onChanged;

void init() {
    someProperty.addListener(new WeakChangeListener<>(changeListener)); // OK, but requires an extra field + WeakChangeListener
}
```

Is there any other solution to set a listener with a lambda without much boilerplate code?

**Edit:**
An other confusing situation exists, while not related to Lambda expressions but still related to the usage of weak references with JavaFX, where the following code won't work:

```
private final ObservableList<Person> persons = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

public ObservableList<Person> getPersons() {
    return FXCollections.unmodifiableObservableList(persons); // a client invoking getPersons().addListener(someListener) won't be notified
}
```

But this code will work (with some additional boilerplate code though):

```
private final ObservableList<Person> persons = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
private final ObservableList<Person> immutableList = FXCollections.unmodifiableObservableList(persons); // needed for our clients to be notified

@SuppressWarnings("ReturnOfCollectionOrArrayField") // needed to avoid a warning
public ObservableList<Person> getPersons() {
    return this.immutableList;
}
```

I'm using the word "confusing" here because:

- The working solution is not the one we come first; it's not "natural".
- When we face the problem for the very first time, it takes hours before we understand where the problem comes from.

Comment: I think the use of weak listeners in the library code has generally not worked out very well. The most common problems arise using bindings. Tomas Mikula discusses this briefly in his [blog](http://tomasmikula.github.io/blog/2015/02/10/the-trouble-with-weak-listeners.html)

Comment: Note that when you replace `this::onChanged` with an anonymous class instance creation, i.e `new ChangeListener<String>() { … }`, the problems are exactly the same. The first creates a strong reference to the outer instance, the second allows the listener to get collected immediately. Generally, weak listeners almost never work as intended, so performing explicit deregistration when necessary, is unavoidable.